# Antiderivative of $\frac {dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

This is probably a very simple  question, but I think its interesting.

What I would think, based on my intuition (which I think is correct in this case) is that 
$$\int \frac {dy}{dx}=y$$
However, to me it doesn't seem like there is something you are "integrating with respect to", meaning
$$\int \frac {dy}{dx}(?)$$

doesn't have an extra d(something) tacked on to the end, like most other antiderivatives do.

If you tried to make the "dy" the thing you "tacked on", then it would become
$$\int \frac 1{dx}dy$$
Which doesn't make any sense to me at all.

So, my question is, if you were trying to solve this without simply recognizing that the antiderivative of a derivative is just the function itself, then how would you solve it?

Apologies for this question being very vague.

Comment: Remember that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a _function_ with respect to $x$. This means that, like any other $f(x)$, integrating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ occurs with respect to $x$. In your notation, this is $\int \frac{dy}{dx}dx$.

Comment: @DavidKraemer Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to find an antiderivative with respect to *something*.

Since it is unspecified, the antiderivative of $\;\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\;$ will *implicitly* be made with respect to the same variable of derivation. $x$.

$$\int \dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}\mathrm d x = y+c$$

What else can you do?